# two-way ANCOVA: Analysis of Covariance in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic, openoffice-basic, ancova

Following [this feature request](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=130835), I want to know if/how I can have a macro to provide a simple GUI to do two-way ANCOVA (Analysis of Covariance) in Open/LibreOffice Calc. There is already [an ANOVA tool](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Data_Statistics_in_Calc#Analysis_of_Variance_.28ANOVA.29) in Calc, which does not comply with my understanding of the method ([reference](http://www.statsmakemecry.com/smmctheblog/stats-soup-anova-ancova-manova-mancova)):

> categorical dependent variable(s) and quantitative response

as it seems to only accept continuous variables! So it is kind of an ANCOVA which only accepts covariants? I'm not really sure ([example](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/79611/the-rows-per-sample-tab-in-anova-calculation-is-always-deactivated/)).

Searching the internet I found [this post](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=55935) and [these lecture materials](https://wiki.uib.no/psychmethods/index.php/T-test_and_Analysis_of_Variance_(ANOVA)) that both suggest a manual separation of the response variable based on the groups of the categorical dependant variable, which is not really a solution. So I would like to make a plugin/macro, probably in Open/LibreOffice-BASIC which provides a GUI for the user to select:

- one categorical independent variable (factor)
- one quantitative independent variable (covariate)
- one quantitative response variable

and then

- gives an APA-compliant table representing the bivariate correlation between the two quantitative variables grouped by the categorical variable
- scatter plot of the two quantitative variables distinguished by color based on the categorical variable, and trend lines and equation for the linear regression for each group.

I know it is too much to ask in one post, but I wasn't sure how I could separate it into smaller questions. Thanks for your support in advance.

**P.S.** There is the [Office Statistics Tools plugin](https://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/office-statistics-tools) originally written for OpenOffice, which seems to do the one-way ANOVA. However, the author [here](https://github.com/imacat/stattool/issues/1#issuecomment-280838830) says that it is faulty and should not be used.