# grouping a column of categorical variable into a set of unique values

Tags: libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic, openoffice-basic

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60504343/4999991), I want to know how I can specify a column/row of a specific sheet including a categorical variable, in Open/LibreOffice BASIC script/macro and get the unique list (i.e., set) of the values.

For example, consider the below dataset:

```
        A,   B,      C
1. gender, age, height
2.    man,  34,    180
3.  woman,  23,    155
4.    man,  54,    165
5.  other,  37,    172
6.  woman,  19,    169
```

Now I want to specify the column tag `A` or header `gender` in `Sheet1` and get the unique values stored in an array `woman, man, other`. It should be noted that

- empty cells must be ignored
- the length of the column is not known

I would appreciate if you could help me know how I can write a BASIC function which gets the column tag or header and the sheet name and returns the set of the categorical values as mentioned above. Thanks for your support in advance.

Comment: Sets are built into Python; are you sure that Basic is your choice? As for finding the last row, see if any of these answers help - https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/145593/select-last-cell-in-column-with-a-macro/.

Comment: I have actually already decided to move on to Python. However, I can't find the Python executable as I have asked [here](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/232282/).

Comment: @JimK BTW If I figure out the reading the column/row into an array, then converting the array into a set shouldn't be impossible. for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017852/vba-get-unique-values-from-array).

Comment: I have successfully tested python-uno macros on macOS in the past, so it should be possible. However, I only own systems with windows or linux. Hopefully, someone on the askLO site has macOS and can answer your question.

Comment: @JimK yeah the Python scripts run. but the location of the executable is not known! ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Try `python -v` in a terminal, or run from code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749711/how-to-get-the-python-exe-location-programmatically.

Comment: @JimK Well, Fining my Python executable is no problem. The issue as I have explained [here](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/232282/) Is that I can't find the Python executable embedded into the LO. So it seems the `/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice` is the Python executable which doesn't make sense!

Comment: @JimK I asked the same question with python [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60541655/4999991)